# How do I define multiple blocks in one module and include different javascript for each?

Tags: 8, blocks

**In Drupal 8**

I understand that to create a block I create a file in this structure:

```
mymodule/src/Plugin/Block/MyModuleBlock.php
```

If I would like to create another block for this module, or even a dozen blocks in this module, where do I define them so that they render differently and contain different javascript/css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following folder structure to create multiple custom blocks in drupal 8

```
-mymodule
--src
---Plugin
----Block
-----block1.php
-----block2.php
-----block3.php
```